SQL : include values where all the values in a column is a certain string
I need to pull each item and component from a table where the component(s) that make up the item is valid. I also need to include any items where all of its components are decommissioned
Example data table:



Item_Number
Item_Status
Component
Component_Status




1
Valid
A
Decommissioned


1
Valid
B
Valid


1
Valid
C
Valid


2
Valid
D
Decommissioned


2
Valid
E
Decommissioned


3
Valid
F
Decommissioned


3
Valid
G
Valid



Expected result:



Item Number
Item Status
Component
Component Status




1
Valid
B
Valid


1
Valid
C
Valid


2
Valid
D
Decommissioned


2
Valid
E
Decommissioned


3
Valid
G
Valid



I feel like there's a way to sole for this using a subquery or CTE but I haven't been able to figure it out yet. I tried pulling the data in by a combination of COMPONENT_STATUS but it didn't seem to work

You can do:
select *
from t
where Component_Status = 'Valid' 
  or not exists (
    select 1 from t x where x.item_number = t.item_number
    and x.Component_Status = 'Valid'
  )

Result:
 item_number  item_status  component  component_status 
 ------------ ------------ ---------- ---------------- 
 1            Valid        B          Valid            
 1            Valid        C          Valid            
 2            Valid        D          Decommissioned   
 2            Valid        E          Decommissioned   
 3            Valid        G          Valid            

See running example at db<>fiddle.

Maybe. I suspect there are some other status than just valid or decomissioned to look at, as well. That's mainly on the OP for asking an incomplete question, but I still like to think ahead that way.

This did exactly what I needed it to! Thanks a bunch

@Guhifdgh, when you get a great answer, upvote! And also accept the (best) answer that solves your problem.
